# c# blazor server - pass class object from child to parent

Tags: c#, blazor, parent-child, blazor-server-side

Hello

I am trying to make a reusable component in blazor server

A list box, where I pass an id (which it used to populate itself, and then what the user selects is passed back

My idea is to pass an ID to a component, from a parent to child, which works fine, but I can only get a string back from the child and I would like to send a class object back, is it possible, I have tried the below

**parent**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

@page "/"

@code {

    private void IwasGivendatabackfromclient(HagClass x)
    {
        string text = x.parChildSet;
        
    }


}


<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<HagChild GiveMeDatFromPar="Balls of steel" OnEmployeeDeleted="IwasGivendatabackfromclient"></HagChild>
```

**Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

namespace Blazor_PH_Par_Child.Shared
{
    public class HagClass
    {
        public  string parSentMe { get; set; }
        public string parChildSet { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Child**

```
@code {


    [Parameter]
    public string GiveMeDatFromPar { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<object> OnEmployeeDeleted { get; set; }

    HagClass x = new HagClass();

    public void Delete_Click()
    {
        x.parChildSet = "test";

        OnEmployeeDeleted.InvokeAsync(x);
        


        }
}


<h3>HagChild</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-1"
        @onclick="Delete_Click">
    Delete
</button>

<p>hello @GiveMeDatFromPar</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can add Parameter like this

```
[Parameter] 
public EventCallback<MyModel> OnEmployeeDeleted { get; set; }
```

Then after the button that deletes clicked, you create the item type of Mymodel and send it back to parent

```
MyModel model = new(){  .... }
OnEmployeeDeleted.InvokeAsync(model);
```

In parent page you have to create function that gets the child data.

```
private void GetDeletedInfo(Mymodel model){}
```

The call of component will be

```
<HagChild OnEmployeeDeleted="data => GetDeletedInfo(data)" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

That does work, strange this is, VS says there's is an error, but allowed compile and the values do come back if stepped in debug

Parent 

<HagChild GiveMeDatFromPar="Balls of steel" OnEmployeeDeleted="IwasGivendatabackfromclient"></HagChild>

Comment: CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'

Comment: Then you have to do like this: <HagChild OnEmployeeDeleted="data =>GetDeletedInfo(data)" /> , i have updated it in my answer too.

Comment: Complier does not work properly every time in Blazor. Is some cases indicates that are some errors but if the program builds then everything is ok. I hope in .net 6 they will fix this issue.

Comment: reloaded VS and it worked great, thank you, life saver